# Share a printer connected to Ubuntu 16.04 with machines on local wi-fi network

Tags: networking, printing, 16.04, sharing

I just did a fresh install of 16.04 and am having trouble sharing my printer with other machines (Ubuntu, Windows and Android) over my wi-fi network.

In earlier versions of Ubuntu it was pretty straight forward to share and publish a printer. (See http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/how-to-share-a-printer-in-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-lts/)

In 16.04 I cannot find anyway to share my USB printer.  There does not seem to be the option of choosing server and settings as shown in the above link.

I have read that 16.04 ships without Python 2 and that affects Windows printer detection.  I am wondering if this is connected to the problem I am having.

Basically, I cannot figure out how to have other machines on my wi-fi network find the printer connected to my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I thought I had this problem - the menu bar had disappeared from the Printer Settings dialog! Then I remembered that by default the menu appears in the screen title bar, not the window title bar... Oops!

Answer (score 3):

This manual worked for me: [Manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu#Ubuntu_print_server) . Read **Ubuntu print server** section. The option to enable is called - "Publish shared printers connected to this server". Once enabled Ubuntu print server published without restart all locally connected printers. Also printer automatically appeared on another Ubuntu 16.04 system without any printer IPP address editing.